# Check if model belongs to user for specific routes - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to check if a recipe belongs to the logged in user. The best way is middleware I guess.

So I created a middleware: AuthRecipe, containing the following code:

```
 $repo = new RecipeRepository;
 $recipe = $repo->getById($request->recipes);

 if($recipe->user_id !== $request->user()->id)
 {
    return redirect()->to('/');
 }
```

In the RecipeController I use the middleware like:

```
$this->middleware('auth.recipe', ['only' => ['update', 'edit', 'destroy']]);
```

This works fine, if the recipe doesn't belong to the user, the user gets redirected to home, but...

Now I have duplicated code. If the recipe belongs to the user, it will get the recipe inside the middleware, but also in the controller itself. So I already know the recipe and don't need to get the recipe again in the controller.

[image]

Of course I can use a method in the model itself.

```
public function auth() {
    if($this->user_id !== Auth::user()->id) {
        redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
```

But then I have to call that method for every method that needs to be protected. I think the middleware is more cleaner. Calling `$recipe->auth()` is not really a controller's responsibility.

Is there some way to pass the recipe data from the middleware to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea 1:**

You could use Route Model Binding:

Per the Laravel docs:

> Laravel route model binding provides a convenient way to inject class instances into your routes. For example, instead of injecting a user's ID, you can inject the entire User class instance that matches the given ID.
>
> [...]
>
> Since we have bound the {user} parameter to the App\User model, a User instance will be injected into the route. So, for example, a request to profile/1 will inject the User instance which has an ID of 1.
>   ```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-model-binding

This way you can load the model once and pass it directly to the controller (assuming it passes middleware)

**EDIT:**

Once the model is bound in the route's boot method, you can access it in the controller like so:

```
public function getUser(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) 
{
    //
}
```

---

**Idea 2:**

Another idea would be to cache the model the first time it is loaded, then you do not need to worry as much about loading the model multiple times as it will be loaded from cache.  Using redis or memcache cache will be very fast.

```
$user = Cache::rememberForever('user_'. $user_id, function() use ($user_id) 
{
    return User::find($user_id);
});
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache

However the downfall of this is that you would need to work out clearing the cache when changes are made to the model (you can do this using events/listeners)

Comment: Thank you! This already helped me a lot. I could get the recipe in the middleware by using $request->recipes (after using `$router->model('recipes', 'App\Models\Recipe');`). But I'm not sure how to get in the controller. `public function edit($id)` this is the method I tried as second parameter: `Recipe $recipe` and `Request $request` and then `$request->recipes`. Both didn't work.

Comment: I'm willing to cache as much as possible, but I had that in mind for the end of the project. First perfect-ionize the project then speed it up with caching :) Thanks for idea of event listeners I did it before inside the repositories. Events are better

Comment: Personally I would use the caching method.  Start developing the cache now because going through later and adding a bunch of events/listeners will be a real pain, especially if it is a large project.  Also you may miss one or two resulting in a hard to debug issue with your code, at least that's my experience.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. But I'm a bit of a perfectionist. So I would like to know if like in this case a query is called twice. Caching solves that problem completely, but the application still holds a flaw. I can use array as caching driver to stop caching while keeping the methods though. But I still would like to solve this problem :)

Comment: awesome! `public function edit(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)` worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: k, I edited the code for future viewers.  Glad I could help.